# How can I change the precedence of groups in a (.NET) regular expression?

Tags: .net, regex

I'm trying to construct a .NET regular expression that matches the following:

1. The string must be composed of alphanumeric identifiers separated by dots
2. There must be a minimum of 2 elements (one dot) but no limit on the maximum
3. The last element must begin with an upper case character.

Here's what I've tried:

```
^(\w+)(\.\w+){0,1}(\.[A-Z]\w+)$
^(\w+)(\.\w+)?(\.[A-Z]\w+)$
```

The results I'm getting are:

`Flubber.flobber.Blobber` - Successful match (correct)
`Flubber.flobber.blobber` - No match (correct: last element does not start with upper case)
`A.B` - No match (incorrect). This meets all the rules and should succeed.

The problem is obviously that the expression is matching the second term and then there is no input left to match the final term. How can I change this behavior so the final term takes precedence?

Comment: I'm a bit short on time to work on this now, but I recall "greedy" versus "lazy" for qualifiers. I just found it. I suspect this is the tool needed to solve your problem. Once youj find the actual answer, you can post it below in the Your Answer. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/quantifiers-in-regular-expressions#Greedy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made two changes to your code

```
^(\w+)(\.\w+)*(\.[A-Z]\w*)$   // new code, make the last character 
      // following the capital optional so it'll match only one capital letter at the end

      // and swapped out the first "?" with "*" to match more than two or three "groups"

^(\w+)(\.\w+)?(\.[A-Z]\w+)$   // your code
```

See https://regex101.com/r/WtEGuG/3

Your code wasn't working for `Ax.Bx.Cx.Dx` as well for `A.B`